# Aiming to write a page in iframe but "Jquery is undefined" in IE but works everywhere else

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, iframe

I am finishing up a website (www.pickmixmagazine.com/wordpress), I have a function that onclick on one of the big squares, data is loaded into the sliding iframe (try it out!) and i am trying to load information from the server using ajax and writing the data into an iframe as shown below.  It works perfectly in firefox and chrome,  just that in IE i keep getting the error **'$' is undefined** and i can't access any Jquery.  Here is the code (I have only included the ajax part of the function):

```
function changeFrame(i)
    {
        var elm = parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
        var topval = $(elm).css('top');

        if(i!='' && i!='home' && window.top==window.self){
            //$('iframe.primary').attr('src', 'http://www.pickmixmagazine.com/wordpress/'+i);

            var ifrm = document.getElementById("mainframe")
            ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
            //var doc = w.document.documentElement;
            //w.contentWindow.location.replace('http://www.pickmixmagazine.com/wordpress/'+i);



            var xhr = $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://www.pickmixmagazine.com/wordpress/'+i,
                    success: function(data) {
                      ifrm.document.open();
                       ifrm.document.write(data);
                       ifrm.document.close();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you loading any other JS libraries as well as jQuery?

Comment: No other libraries, but a lot of jquery scripts, but thats it

Comment: Try `ifrm = ifrm.contentWindow;` without all those ternaries.

Comment: Same situation with "ifrm = ifrm.contentWindow"

Comment: Does the iframe run any jQuery at all? That's weird.

Comment: none at all, all the CSS comes through but no jQuery

Comment: it doesn't load any javascript aat all in fact (tried to alert outside of document ready)

Comment: Every question about IE always contains the phrase "but it works everywhere else."

Answer (score 0):

It sounds almost like something is causing a naming conflict with $. Although the fact that this issue only manifests itself in IE is a tad odd.

Some what of a shot in the dark, but you could try to undefine the $ identifier and attempt running your code in a surrogate function:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($) {
       //put all JQuery related code here.

 });
```